# How to get an image using curl?

Tags: c++, curl, libcurl

I'm having trouble getting an image from a URL using curl. It works if I pass the URL in as the constructor of an ImageMagick Image object. But using curl I'm not having much luck and I need to use curl.

Right now I'm doing...

```
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url.c_str());
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, &curlCallback);
curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);
curl_easy_perform(curl);
```

And then

```
size_t curlCallback(char* buf, size_t size, size_t nmemb, void* up) 
{                                                                   
    ofstream out;
    out.open("/home/name/Desktop/img.png");
    out.write(buf, nmemb * size);

    return size * nmemb;
}
```

It does seem to get the start of a PNG, but not the whole thing. It only returns 251 bytes (header info or something maybe??). An image viewer will open it as a png and know its resolution, but the image itself is blank. If I print the buffer to console, I see ?PNG and then the binary data symbol.

I know its not a problem with the remote host because if I use ImageMagick:

```
Image image = Image(url);
```

Then I get the image in its entirety and can save it and it's just fine.

Comment: `curlCallback` can be called multiple times during the download (see the docs [http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/curl_easy_setopt.html]). Using `CURLOPT_WRITEDATA` passing in a FILE* might be easier.

Comment: Good call, armed with this new knowledge I have defeated the problem. If you'd like to write that as an answer I will choose it as the solution.

Comment: Added it as a comment since I didn't have tools to try the proposed solution out, glad you figured it out.

Comment: It's been a few years, but now the link does not work anymore and plus... images are not so easy to download.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function set with `CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION` (`curlCallback` in your case) can be called multiple times during the download (see the docs).

Using `CURLOPT_WRITEDATA` passing in a `FILE*` might be easier.